# All page show 404 apart from index

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Even /home is 404. I just start learning laravel, I don't know if I did something wrong.
After reinstall composer and created a new project the problem still 
exist.
Xampp is running.

Here is the .htaccess in public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your Apache *mod_rewrite* enabled and do you have *.htaccess* in your *public* folder?

Comment: Hi TheFallen, yes and yes.

Comment: How do you access the project in the browser? Using virtual host, some URL?

Comment: I created the project in xampp folder and access it by "localhost/projectname"

Comment: Can you make a virtual host and see if it works then?

Comment: Do you allow to override your `.htaccess` in your virtualhost configuration?

Comment: Still fail after made a virtual host following this: https://delanomaloney.com/2013/07/10/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/

Comment: Hi antoineB, how to check if it is allowed to override .htaccess in virtualhost configuration?

Comment: @Akid You should have an "allow override All" somewhere in your apache configuration file.

Comment: Setted "allow override" to "All" but still not work, just gave up, I am now working in VM, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

have you added Route::get(/home, HomeController@index); to your routes file?